# How to Hide Columns in Form Based on Checkbox in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

My Concern while I'm creating a database using access is that I create a form named "Inquiries"
in this form I select all columns from the needed table, so whenever I want to search for some data I just write the word that I need in text box and all record will show up. (Using some coding). So, after this records show up, I want to make some criteria, where some columns should Appear only if I click on the related checkbox, if the value of the checkbox is checked the columns will appear if it is not check will not appear in the form. (See the Attached Picture).[image]

The Keyword Search code I already create it 
but the second feature that related to the criteria, I'm not sure how to do it.
That's why I need your help in this so I can Design my form and report as per my manager needs

Comment: `AND ([Purpose] = TextFromPusposeFilter OR NOT PurposeCheckbox)` (or LIKE instead of equal). When checkbox is checked, second part of condition is False and the result of whole condition is equal the result of its first part. When checkbox is not checked, the second part is True, and the whole condition is True independent of the result of its first part (assuming it cannot be Null - when no data, it is to be an empty string).

Comment: Where should I write this expression?       (AND ([Purpose] = TextFromPusposeFilter OR NOT PurposeCheckbox))                                                Also I want to be sure what you mean by " TextFromPurposeFilter" is it refers to the Purpose filed in the form? And                                              "UrposeCheckbox" refers to the checkbox name

Comment: In Your SQL query text, of course... and replace short placeholders with full names/paths to Your control' values. Someting like `Forms("FilterForm").Form.Controls("PurposeChechBox").Value`

Comment: And if You want not only ignore this field in data filtering when checkbox is unchecked, but additionally hide this field on the form face at all, You must create Checkbox_Click method code and alter field.visible property in it dependent of current checkbox value.

Comment: What code should be applied here?

Comment: Something like `PurposeField.Visible = PurposeChechbox.Value`.